# Magento2 when navigating from admin to Web Setup Wizard produces 404 page

Tags: magento2, 404-page, web-setup-wizard

Magento 2.0.2 installed from composer, when I try to navigate to Web Setup Wizard:
http://mg2.com/admin_url/admin/backendapp/redirect/app/setup/
It takes me to http://mg2.com/setup which in turn produces 404 page
Magento is setup to use `/pub` as document root, with apache mod_php
Any ideas why is it not working?

Update:

Since Magento was configured with pub as site root, I decided that this might cause the issue, so I changed apache config to serve from Magento root. 
Did not make any difference, still http://mg2.com/setup produces 404

Comment: any error log available Petar?

Comment: unfortunately none. I should mention that Magento was installed from cli so i didn't need to access web wizard during install.

Comment: Did you check file permissions?

Comment: Oh yeah, file permissions are fine. This is developer site, so server runs under my personal user. Compilation completes fine.

Comment: Anything in server logs?

Comment: Nothing besides the 404 in access log. In any case, restarting the server and serving from Magento root seems to have enabled the access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you have the case of Magento being served out of `pub` one solution to have access to `setup` is to configure an alias. To do that in apache, you may do something like the following.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName m2.local
    ServerAdmin jamby77@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/magento202/pub"

    <Directory "/var/www/magento202/pub">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias "/setup" "/var/www/magento202/setup"
    Alias "/update" "/var/www/magento202/update"
</VirtualHost>
```

Probably not the most elegant solution but it works.

Comment: Hi, I am still not able to access admin dashboard, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

first, you are right, when the webserver is configured to have the pub/ directory as root (which is the right way in a production env) the /setup path is not reachable, since it is installed in the path magento_root/setup.

The key question here would then be how you installed magento from cli and if everything was installed correctly.

You should have a /setup directory in you magento root containing all needed files https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/setup

**===EDIT===**

although I'm not sure how this is handled when you are navigating from admin and have the pub directory as web root. My second thought is that this should work, but I have not testet it yet

Comment: I installed using composer. Everything else worked fine and works fine. Event if served fro pub, setup should be reachable, it is being redirected to specific router from web setup wizard menu. I am trying to perform upgrade to 2.0.3 as described in the documents.

Comment: Just an update, changing site document root to Magento root, and restarting apache gave me access to setup, it is still however good to know if it is not supposed to work at all when served from pub, or if it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error when I switched the web server config to point to /pub instead of /.

Reverting the above back to / fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just create symlink inside pub directory:

> ln -s ../setup setup

After this you will be able to navigate to Web Setup Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

pub and setup are at the same level, you won't be able to run the Web Setup Wizard if pub is your root. It's designed that way so that if you use pub as your docroot in production, no one can access the Web Setup Wizard.

Here's what we advise: "create another subdomain or docroot that uses the Magento installation directory as its root."

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was:

```
Base URLs (Secure)
-> Use Secure URLs on Storefront -> Yes
-> Use Secure URLs in Admin -> Yes
-> Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) -> Yes
-> Upgrade Insecure Requests -> Yes

php bin/magento cache:clean
```